# How to write bytes from input with offsets in a binary file?

Tags: python, binary, byte

I am trying to create a bin file with script below which should write bytes from user input and with offset bytes in between every character. But there is a problem where it writes sequentially all bytes and does not separate after each byte with added offset byte defined with 'shift'.

[image]

```
offset is 2 bytes    p        y        t        h        o        n
00000000 00000000 00110001 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

How I want it to be

```
offset 2 bytes      p      offset 2 bytes      y      offset 2 bytes        t    offset 2 bytes , etc
00000000 00000000 00110001 00000000 00000000 00110001 00000000 00000000 00110001 00000000 00000000 00110000 00000000 00000000 00110000 00000000 00000000 00110000 00000000 00000000 00110000 00000000 0000000
```

Here is the code for the program

```
fdata = open("text.bin","wb")
fmeta = open("key.bin","w+b")
print('Enter text:')
txt='python' # input()
l=len(txt)
print(l, 'bytes')
strtobin= ' '.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(txt, 'utf-8'))
print(strtobin)

# even bytes in key [xor 1]
for v in range(0, 25, 2):
    #print(v)
    fmeta.seek(v)
    fmeta.write(bytes(0))

shift=int(2)
sh=shift.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
# odd bytes in key 
for a in range(1,25):
    if a % 2 != 0:
        #print(a)
        fmeta.seek(a)
        fmeta.write(sh)

# text bin [xor 2]
pos=0
#for i in range(1,10): #(len(txt)+10)
for elem in strtobin.split():
    el1=elem.encode('ascii')
    print (el1)
    #print(elem)
    pos = pos + sh
    fdata.seek(pos,1)
    fdata.write(el1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

PAD = b'\x00\00'

with Path("in.txt").open("r") as infile, Path("out.bin").open("wb") as  out_file:
    for line in infile:
        for char in line:
            out_file.write(PAD)
            out_file.write(char.encode())
     out_file.write(PAD)
```

just write `PAD` after every character and a the very end of the file.

if `"in.txt"` just consists of the string `"python"` that should more or less reproduce your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but your code looks awfully complicated for what it's trying to do.

Why not just

```
for ch in text:
     <Not sure if you want to write 2 0's or skip two bytes>
     Write ch as a byte
```

Skipping two bytes is `file.seek(2, 1)`

Comment: I wanted to skip two bytes after each byte (for a character), so I can later read those bin files with seek and specific offset values known only to the creator of this code.